# Problems with Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

**I am using SQLServer 2008 Enterprise Edition running in Windows 7 Home Premium Edition**,  and I am having problems with the reporting service. The Reporting Service Configuration Manager does not show neither the Report Service Web Server Url nor the Report Manager URL. However, if I bring closer the mouse to the place where the aforementioned Urls should be a tooltip with the value of these addresses appears.

Using this *invisible* url I go to Report Manager and it is empty in spite of the fact that I have made an apparent successful deploy of some reports from my Visual Studio 2008.

In addition, when attempting to see the reports through the Report Service Web URL it gives me the following error :

*"The permissions granted to user yamil PC yamil ' plow insufficient for performing this operation. ( rsAccessDenied ) "*

At last, no one of the web sites related with Reporting Services appears in the Internet Information Services Configuration Manager.  Is this normal?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like permission or UAC error to me. By default, BUILTIN\Administrators or the local admin group on computer would have content manager role on RS. If you are already part of this group and you still see the error, You need to right click on your IE's icon and "Run as Administrator" before you try to browse the Report Server URL which throws the error.

For Report Manager URL, if its greyed out, URL reservation for Report Manager is not done. See if Apply button is enabled, If it is, Clicking on the Apply button under Report Manager tab should take care of it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Using "Run as administrator" has solved everything. However in the reporting Services Configuration Manager the url are steel invisible and I only obtain information about them through a tooltip when I move the cursor of the mouse near by the place the URL must be.

Comment: If you don't want to keep using "Run as administrator", Click on Folder Settings -> Security -> New Role Assignment -> Add your domain\account to "Content Manager" role for complete permissions on RS instance.

I would'nt worry about URL reservation if my Report manager is accessible. Also, If you are using hostheader to access your RS instance the URL could be greyed by default.

Comment: But, what folder? Where are the deployed reports?

Comment: I mean go to Report Manager http://servername/Repors, you would see Folder options at the home itself.

Comment: This is the answer, even in SQL Server Reporting Services **2019**. Just click the Apply button on the Web Service URL tab, and then on the Web Portal URL tab. In my case, the Apply button was enabled, but then I'm an admin user on my machine. Also, note that from SSRS 2019, the config manager is now called Report Server Configuration Manager, which wasted an hour of my time trying to find it in the start menu by typing Reporting Services.... Also it's in a shared folder within Program Files now, so presumably not specific to a SQL Server version (2019, 2022, 2028 etc.) anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the user you are trying to login with is an administrator. Once that is done you should be able to go into the report manager url as specified in Reporting Services Configuration Manager.